# Combine two different tables with similar column. SQL Server, Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Say I have two Tables with same columns

> ### tblfamilyHead

```
id f_name  mi  l_name   address

1  Dizon   T.   Gomez   Canada
2  Edgar   R.   Curtis  California
```

> ### tblfamilyMember

```
id  headid   f_name   mi  l_name   address

1    1       michael  A.  Gomez    Canada
2    1       Sharon   A.  Gomez    Canada
3    2       Curt     C.  Curtis   California
```

And I want the expected result as the following:

```
id  f_name  mi  l_name  address

1   Dizon   T.  Gomez   Canada
2   Edgar   R.  Curtis  California
1   michael A.  Gomez   Canada
1   Sharon  A.  Gomez   Canada
2   Curt    C.  Curtis  California
```

please help me with this. Thank you.

Comment: Use `union all`

Comment: I've gotta try as answers below

Comment: Ok!. union all is what i've lookin' for. tnx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably lokking to `UNION ALL` both the table like

```
select id, f_name,  mi,  l_name,   address from tblfamilyHead
union all
select headid,   f_name,   mi,  l_name,   address from tblfamilyMember
```

Comment: tnx for ur response. Let me try this.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `UNION ALL` set operator:

```
SELECT id
,      f_name
,      mi 
,      l_name 
,      address
FROM   tblfamilyHead 
UNION ALL
SELECT headid Id
,      f_name 
,      mi 
,      l_name
,      address
FROM   tblfamilyMember
```

Comment: tnx for ur response. I'll be back with result of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Use UNION to combine 2 tables with same number of columns:

```
SELECT a,b,c FROM table1
UNION
SELECT a,b,c FROM table2
```